# conversion of sql queries to xml format

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml

Is there any tool or open source code to convert the sql queries [not the query results] to xml.

Example : if i have a sql query like `select * from employee where empname='jon'`. I want to generate this query in xml format like

```
<root>
   <selectclause>
        <field table=''....>
   </selectclause>
</root>
```

Any plugins or open source code links are needed.

I am using SQL Server & need to extend to MySQL Databases also. However, i code for .Net Framework 4 in C#

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @John: I have edited the post to mention the database details & programming language used.

Comment: Is there some standard SQL Query XML schema you want to use or is this something you're defining? Also, just out of curiosity, why would you do this?

Comment: @mwan100: I want to store sql query in xml format. I need the way to parse the SQL Query and split into pieces so that easily i can join them back from xml to sql again.

Comment: I understand what you want to accomplish - but HOW do you want to split the query? What XML schema is it going to end up in? If it's not some standard then you're just going to fall back on C#'s text processing functions to write a SQL to XML parser yourself. But again, I really don't understand why you'd want to do this. What is it accomplishing? The only reason I ask is there may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I currently donot have a schema for the xml that i am going to generate. I have to find one standard schema and use it. The reason for this functionality is that i will store the query in database and allow it to be executed later.

Comment: I was able to use stack and generate an xml for the query.. any ways if there is no pre-existing standards, let me stick on to my developed version..

Answer (score -1):

```
select Customer_ID, Short_Name, Phone, Area,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,Invoice_Date,GETDATE()) <= 21  then Balance end) '21 days',
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,Invoice_Date,GETDATE()) > 21 then Balance end) 'More than 21 days',
    '' Visted, '' DLI, '' Collection
  from vw_pending_invoice 
where route = 1
  group by Customer_ID, Short_Name, Phone, Area
```

Comment: Whats this query for. I did not get you.